# Recursion Problem that causes a StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, out-of-memory

Title of the challenge in HackerRank is 'Recursive Digit Sum'
I just want to know what causes my solution to have a 'StackOverFlowError';
The algorithms need to add all the digits in String n. It adds all the digits in n until the length of n is equivalent to 1.
Here`s my solution in java 8.

```
    public static int superDigit(String n, int k) {
    // Write your code here
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
            sb.append(n);
        }
        return helper(Integer.valueOf(sb.toString()));
    }
    
    public static int helper(int numbers){
        if(numbers < 10) return numbers;
        int sum = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.valueOf(numbers));
        for(int i = 0; i < sb.length();i++){
            sum = sum + Integer.valueOf(sb.charAt(i));
        }
        return helper(sum);
    }
```

Comment: What number is causing the error?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur do I need to convert it to "long" instead of int?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I think this line, sb.append(String.valueOf(numbers));? I'm not sure.

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(sb.charAt(i))` yields the ASCII code for a character, not the numeric value it represents.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur: That might be a problem, but as it is not part of any recursion, it is not what is being asked about.

Comment: Scott has nailed this.  You want `Character.getNumericValue` instead of `Integer.valueOf` in the `for` loop inside `helper`.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur it's absolutely nothing to do with the integer limits in Java.  Please don't send someone off on a wild goose chase.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes, minterpreted it after a quick glance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your method has other issues. I had to look up this problem to see what the goal was.

First, look at the first method. Examples I have seen are `superDigit("28382", 20)` which would far exceed the size of an int.  So first change your method below to call `helper` with a string argument. You can use a loop if you wish but I would just pass the string using repeat (as of Java 11).

```
public static int superDigit(String n, int k) {
       // may need to check for valid values of n and k and handle accordingly
        return helper(n.repeat(k));
}
```

Now the helper method must accept a string.  And you must return if the length of that string is <= 1.  If so, convert the number to an `int` and return it.

Since you already have a string you don't need `StringBuilder` as `String` also has a `charAt` method.   So now just use the technique discussed in the comments to sum the digits.  You could also use `sum += numbers.charAt(i) - '0';`

Then you need to call helper again to check its length.  So convert `sum` to a string and do so.

```
public static int helper(String numbers){
    // System.out.println(str); //uncomment this to watch
                                // your method do its job
    int sum = 0;
    if(numbers.length <= 1) {
          return Integer.parseInt(numbers);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++){
        sum +=  Integer.valueOf(numbers.charAt(i)) - Integer.valueOf('0');
        // or sum += numbers.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    return helper(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

Now you can call it like this.

```
int sum = superDigit("4929229", 15);
System.out.println(sum);
```